# Why request to site returns error Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox

Ok so, i'm making ajax request to site page, and it doesn't return anything - page is valid, but it gives this error in the console . **Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

How to fix it, i wan't to connect to the page properly.

Comment: Have you tried Googling the error message?

Comment: Where is your script running?  You can only make an AJAX call if you're on the same server *and port*.

Comment: Thanks , fix the problem with getting it again witch ajax, but the request is to a file that contains php file_get_contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this error because of browsers **Same origin policy** which prevents XML HTTP requests(AJAX) to be made to other domains and sub-domains. There are many workarounds of which JSONP is favoured among many developers. But, this requires the server/page to which you're making the request to serve JSONP response.