# Get request to watson tone analyzer api returns No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 401 error

Tags: javascript, ibm-cloud, watson

When I do a get request to sent my content to the watson token analyzer api to get the tone analysis json, it returns a 401 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error. I'm doing this from the client side with javascript.

Is it possible to query the tone analyzer api with a get request from the client side?

Here's what I'm doing:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone?version=2016-05-19&text='+encodeURI(input),
    data:{
        'username':'password'
    },
    contentType:'application/json',
    method:'GET',
    success:function(tone){
        console.log(tone);
    }
});
```

Requesting token client side to use api client side:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token',
    data:{
        'url':'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone',
        'username':'password'
    },
    dataType:'jsonp',
    contentType:'application/javascript',
    method:'GET'
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why request to site returns error Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795560/why-request-to-site-returns-error-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: For whether IBM will allow you to call their API... that sounds like a question for IBM.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan in their help and support, they say post here with the tab ibm-bluemix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Tone Analyzer is CORS supported which allows for option #2 below

You can either:

1. Use the API server side
2. Get an authentication token (expires after 1 hour) on your server side using the [authorization service](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk#authorization). Return that token to your client so your javascript call can use the token when it requests the Tone Analyzer API from your client.

An example for #2 above is [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/tree/master/examples/browserify)

Comment: Can't I get the token from the client side though and then us it client too? I thought that's what this, https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/getting_started/gs-tokens.shtml, is saying, but when I try to run the request for the token, I get an unexpected identifier error in my url and the url looks like a perfectly fine string to me. I've updated my question with the ajax request I'm doing client side

Comment: so from that link i see this quote "You can write an authentication proxy in Bluemix® that obtains and returns a token to your client application, which can then use the token to call the service directly" which makes me believe you must call the authentication service from your server. I am specifically looking at the part "returns a token to your client application which can then use the token to call the service directly"

Comment: i added an example I found to my answer